# Java having two Objects of Same Class with different Values

Tags: java

I have a problem where I want to have two Objects of the same Class. However, all of their variables are in synch somehow and I don't know how to fix this...

For example:
this is the Class of the objects

```
public class Cat 
{
    public static int age;
    public static String breed;
    public static String Name;
    public static String fur;
    
    private Cat (String name)
    {
        age = 5;
        breed = "Birman";
        fur = "soft";
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and this is where I want to create Objects of this Class:

```
public class test 
{
    static Cat Whisky;
    static Cat Ghismo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Whisky.age = 10;
        Ghismo.breed = "Maine Coon";
        
        System.out.println(Whisky.age + " " + Whisky.breed);
        System.out.println(Ghismo.age + " " + Ghismo.breed);
        
    }
}
```

For some reason the output is this:

```
10 Maincoon
10 Maincoon
```

Why does it always give me the same values in the output and how can I fix this?

Comment: Because all the fields in Cat are static.

Comment: You will also need to instantiate your cats with the `new` operator.

Comment: thanks a lot... I'm actually kinda embarrassed I didn't think of this myself...